# C++ Error in overloading << with using vectors

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

I'm trying to display a basic 3 by 3 matrix by using vectors and the << operator. The problem is when I try to run the code I get an error that says no member named size in MatrixViaVector.

In my header file I have:

```
#ifndef homework7_MatrixViaVector_h
#define homework7_MatrixViaVector_h

#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
template <class T>

class MatrixViaVector{

public:
    MatrixViaVector();
    MatrixViaVector(int m,int n);
    template <class H>
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, const MatrixViaVector<H> &obj);
private:
    int m,n;
    vector<vector<T>> matrix;
};

#endif
```

And in my test File I have:

```
    #include "MatrixViaVector.h"

    template <class T>
    MatrixViaVector<T>::MatrixViaVector(){

        //creates a 3 by 3 matrix with elements equal to 0


        for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
            vector<int> row;
            for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
                row.push_back(0);
            matrix.push_back(row);
        }
    }

template <class T>
MatrixViaVector<T>::MatrixViaVector(int m,int n)//creates a m by n matrix????
{
    //creates a matrix with dimensions m and n with elements equal to 0

    for (int i=0;i<m;i++){
        vector<int> row;
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
            row.push_back(0);
        matrix.push_back(row);
    }
}

    template <class T>
    ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, const MatrixViaVector<T> & obj)
    {
        //obj shud have the vector and therefore I should be able to use its size

        for (int i = 0; i < obj.size(); i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < obj.capacity(); j++)
                outs << " "<< obj.matrix[i][j];
            outs<<endl;
        }
        outs<<endl;
        return outs;
    }

    int main()
    {

    MatrixViaVector <int> A;
    MatrixViaVector <int> Az(3,2);//created an object with dimensions 3by2????
    cout<<A<<endl;
    cout<<Az<<endl;//this prints out a 3 by 3 matrix which i dont get????????
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MatrixViaVector<>` dont have function `size()`, but if you intend to use size of vector do as follows:

Change this snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < obj.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < obj.capacity(); j++)
            outs << " "<< obj.matrix[i][j];
        outs<<endl;
    }
```

To

```
for (std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < obj.matrix.size(); i++){
        for (std::vector<int>::size_type j = 0; j < obj.matrix.size(); j++)
            outs << " "<< obj.matrix[i][j];
        outs<<endl;
    }
```

[std::vector::size()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/) and [std::vector::capacity()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/capacity/) are 2 different functions, please check its difference.

Comment: what if the dimensions were different. Like instead of a 3 by 3 we had a 3 by 2 then how would the for loop change?

Comment: @guploo there will not be any change, since boundary of vector<> is checking using vector<>::size() function

Comment: I edited my post with my new error but I tried creating a 3 by 2 matrix but if i try to output it then it still outputs a 3 by 3 matrix

Comment: @guploo better to ask a new question or mark your edit at end of your post with sub heading EDIT, I am not sure what did you edit

Comment: all I did was created another constructor for matrix that works for m by n dimensions and I created another object but Ill mark those changes up in my post

Comment: `cout<Az<<endl;` need to correct to `cout<<Az<<endl;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82336/discussion-between-guploo-and-steephen).

Comment: i still get a 3 by 3 matrix after fixing that error